# How to configure a DD-WRT (micro) secondary router to prevent LAN access on a specified schedule?

Tags: home-networking, dd-wrt, wireless-access-point

I have a NetGear WiFi router configured as the main gateway for internet access in my home, and a secondary router (a Linksys wrt54GS loaded with DD-WRT v24-sp2 micro), configured with a different SSID, for my kids to use to access the internet.  My goal in using DD-WRT is to be able to let my kids use the household Wi-Fi, but to adhere to an electronics curfew  during evening hours, so they are not snap-chatting till the wee hours of the morning.  [Here is the link I used](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point#Long_Version) to configure my DD-WRT.  Basically my DD-WRT WiFi router is:

- Configured in router mode.
- Wireless mode is AP (Access Point)
- SSID is different from my main gateway router.
- Configured on same subnet as main router, as IP 192.168.1.2 (main router is 192.168.1.1).
- DHCP disabled

I have tried setting up a schedule on the Access Restrictions tab, trying several different options (deny access vs filter access to most ports; list individual IPs to deny vs a range of IPs [3-254]; Security->SPI Firewal Enabled vs Disabled).  However, I think this is not the right approach, since this schedule is for "WAN" access, and my 2 routers are chained via LAN ports: the WAN port on the secondary router is not even used.

So far everything I've done is through the web interface.  Is there another way to go about this?  Perhaps write a bash or python script to run on the router that just shuts the LAN off during certain hours?  Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

- Connect DD-WRT router to your LAN via its WAN port
- Configure the WAN access rules as you have

This gives you the advantage of shutting down your kids' internet access during the scheduled times. It *also* allows you to regulate access to other resources within your own network, e.g. a file or media server you might be running.

I implemented a similar setup on my own home network for guest wi-fi access, using it to limit how much of my bandwidth they can consume (I've got more than one friend who doesn't understand the concept of download caps...) and even shutting it down completely when necessary (I had a problem once where a friend, thinking he was being helpful, provided the WPA password to a neighbor who also did not respect bandwidth caps).

If you have your kids' systems in the same subnet as your main LAN, there really shouldn't be a difference in terms of what local resources they can access, however it does give you the control over their WAN access that you want. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't DD-WRT allow you to define exemptions to the schedule, so you could allow them access to local resources even when their WAN is otherwise shut off?) Of course, you could put them in a different subnet, allowing you to more easily use firewalls to gain fine-grained control over what local resources they can and cannot access.

Comment: Ok, I've tried plugging secondary WAN to primary LAN, and set up an access restriction schedule, with various combinations of firewall enabled/disabled, and "Assign WAN Port to Switch" checked/unchecked, and no dice.  All web traffic is still getting through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of a "networking noob", so I'm not sure if configuring my secondary DD-WRT Linksys router on a schedule didn't work because it was essentially functioning as a pass-through router to the primary, and thus was bypassing the NAT and WAN aspect of the router.  Or perhaps maybe I just had something else misconfigured for the normal GUI scheduling tool to work correctly.

However, I can say that what finally did work for me was to set up a pair of cron jobs to disable and enable the wireless radio at specific times using the [wl](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wl_command) command.  My solution:  On the router's Administration tab, go to the Management sub-tab, then find the [Cron](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/CRON) section.  Set Cron to *Enable*, then enter a crontab similar to the following:

```
#Clock Minutes
#|  Clock Hour
#|  |      Day of week
#|  |      |   Run as
#|  |      |   |   Command...
#v  v      v   v   v
30 22  * * * root wl radio off
30 7  * * * root wl radio on
```